# How to pass big data from a factory to a constructor with neither dynamic memory nor unnecessary copies?

Tags: c++, stack-memory, stdmove, elision

Runge-Kutta schemes consist of an algorithm, implemented in `Scheme`, and a piece of data, called `Table` (Butcher tableau).

For the construction of a scheme, we want consumers to use the syntax

```cpp
Scheme s = Factory::makeSchemeXY();
```

where XY identifies the particular table used in scheme. (and there shall be no other way to construct schemes).

The implementation is achieved below with an expression template design pattern, in that effectively the table is an expression template.

Since the table can be huge, the example below uses a shared_ptr so as to avoid that unnecessary copies of the table are created and destroyed.

## Question

What we really want is for a table to be constructed in a factory function, and then stored as an attribute of scheme. How can we do this without the use of dynamic allocation?

The question is relevant to us because we foresee some embedded targets where we won't be able to use dynamic allocation. Also, we hope it to be unnecessary because after all we just want the table as one attribute to be constructed and live.

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include<memory>

class Table;
class Factory;
class Scheme;

class Table{
    friend class Factory;
    friend class Scheme;
    double A=0;
    Table(){}
public:
   ~Table(){std::cout<<"~Table\n";}     // only one table is used, hence avoid instantiation of copy
};

class Scheme{
    std::shared_ptr<Table> pt;
    friend class Factory;
    Scheme()=delete;
    void operator=(Scheme const&)=delete;
public:
    Scheme(std::shared_ptr<Table> pt):pt(pt){}
};

struct Factory{
    Factory()=delete;
    static std::shared_ptr<Table> makeSchemeXY(){
        std::shared_ptr<Table> p( new Table ); // heap allocation won't work on some platforms
        p->A = 42; // the table should be constructed here, not in the scheme. That would become too messy.
        return p; // can't we use std::move, or elision, or something here?
    }
};

struct App{
    Scheme x = Factory::makeScheme();   // <--- highly preferred consumer syntax
};

int main(){
    App a;
}
```

## What we tried

1. We tried elision, in that `makeScheme` returns a `Table` and `Scheme` has an attribute of type `Table`. However, in the example above, this triggers two calls of `~Table`, meaning an unnecessary copy was created.
2. We tried `std::move(t)` in both the return clause of `makeScheme` and the constructor list of `Scheme()`. Still, The mere construction of `t` in both `Table` and `Scheme` triggered two instances of `Table` to live.

Below is a code with un/commented variations for elision and move.
The current un/commenting is compilable but triggers to instantiations of `Table`.

```cpp
#include<iostream>

class Table;
class Factory;
class Scheme;

class Table{
    friend class Factory;
    friend class Scheme;
    double A=0;
    Table(){}
public:
   ~Table(){std::cout<<"~Table\n";}
};

class Scheme{
    friend class Factory;
    Scheme()=delete;
    void operator=(Scheme const&)=delete;
    //
    Table t;
public:
    Scheme(Table t):t(t){} // hope for elision
    //Scheme(Table&& t):t(std::move(t)){} // using move
};

struct Factory{
    Factory()=delete;
    static Table makeScheme(){ Table t; t.A=2; return t; } // hope for elision
    //static Table makeScheme(){ Table t; t.A=2; return std::move(t); }
    //static Table&& makeScheme(){ Table t; t.A=2; return std::move(t); } // pardon my futile attempt
};

struct App{
    Scheme x = Factory::makeScheme();
};

int main(){
    App a;
}
```

Remark: While `Table` *should* be `const`, the employed BLAS interface does not support const types (hence we need Table non-const in Scheme, despite it won't change).

Comment: Totally unrelated: `std::shared_ptr<Table> p( new Table );` -> `std::shared_ptr<Table> p = std::make_shared<table>();`. closes off a possible leak if anything throws between `new table` and `p` taking ownership.

Comment: @user4581301 Ouh. I had no idea. Thank you for that :)

Comment: Will the tables ever change at run-time? And if they do, will the change have to be reflected in all schema object? If the tables won't change at all, why not just simply an array of data, one array for each table, and store a reference or pointer to the array in your schema objects (much like you do now)? And if you need to change the tables globally, then there's no difference, except that the arrays are not constant.

Comment: If each schema object need their own unique copy, then you could create the table as a fixed-size array, and copy a template or original data from somewhere into the array, which can then be modified locally. No dynamic allocation, but each schema object creation needs a memory copy operation.

Comment: And in the last case, if the size is not known at compile-time, or can be changed at run-time, there's really no way against either dynamic allocation; Or allocate enough memory for each schema object at compile-time, so that reallocation will never happen. Which could waste a lot of memory that sits unused.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Interesting. So you propose the Factory becomes a singleton with arrays of all tables, and then the respective scheme gets one pointer to the respective table? I can think of two issues: 1) There are many tables, so while currently we can prevent instantation of tables in deployed code (to save memory) I do not see how this would work if we had to keep table instances available at any time. 2) The tables must be of different accuracy, depending on the number type the user chooses (Factory<Tfloat>, and are then being calculated with fixed-point solvers for that type.

Comment: Recommendation: Let's see the code for at least try 1. It may be tweak-able. try 2 with the move may not be worth exploring. For example moved-from objects still need to be destroyed. The savings are in transferring the guts of one instance to another. If you can't efficiently transfer the data in a `Table`, move is not useful to you.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I agree with you we could actually copy arrays. So we are talking Tfloat A[n][n], b[n], c[n], where n=10~50. But I am curious whether something in the spirit of std::move could be possible, to improve efficacy, brevity and potential for errors.

Comment: @user4581301. Yes. Let me get it up and running, and then I place it below.

Comment: So effectively, you want the Table attribute of Scheme to be instantiated in place on the stack without superfluous moves or copies? If you are willing to deviate from your syntax slightly, you could pass a factory function for table to the constructor of Scheme, instead of passing the table. Then scheme could use the factory function to instantiate the table. Your syntax would change from `Scheme x = Factory::makeScheme()` to `Scheme x = Factory::makeScheme` but this may violate the rule of least surprise

Comment: @joergbrech. This looks very interesting! So the idea is to assign not a function _call_ but the function itself to Scheme. I am not at all familiar to this. I will try to understand this, but if you like, would you be willing to explain how it would be implemented; happily as comment or answer. I would upvote it :)

Comment: Which version of the std do you use? And will your future embedded compiler conform to that std?   [RVO](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision) should be mandatory since c++17 .  [...] you could try to inject the function that constructs the table into `Scheme`s constructor. Then table would be a return value in `Scheme, which in turn is a return value .... no, `Table` already is the return value (I don't seem to understand how `Scheme` gets into all this).  Anyway, the return value already should be optimised!? Maybe all boils down to an old c++ std version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are willing to deviate from your calling syntax slighlty, you could pass the factory function for `Table` to the constructor of `Scheme`. Then this constructor could instantiate the table attribute in place without any copies or moves. Your consumer would call

```cpp
Scheme s = Factory::makeSchemeXY
```

instead of `Scheme s = Factory::makeSchemeXY()`, which may look surprising and thus may violate the [principle of least surprise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment).

```cpp
#include<iostream>

class Table;
class Factory;
class Scheme;

class Table{
    friend class Factory;
    friend class Scheme;
    double A=0;
    Table(){}
public:
   ~Table(){std::cout<<"~Table\n";}
};

class Scheme{
    friend class Factory;
    Scheme()=delete;
    void operator=(Scheme const&)=delete;
    //
    Table t;
public:
    template <typename FactoryFunction>
    Scheme(FactoryFunction const& f):t(f()) {}
    //
    // or optionally template-free:
    // Scheme( Table(*f)(void) ):t(f()){}
};

struct Factory{
    Factory()=delete;
    static Table makeScheme(){ Table t; t.A=2; return t; }
};

struct App{
    Scheme x = Factory::makeScheme;
};

int main(){
    App a;
}
```

Output

```
~Table
```

[Live Code](https://godbolt.org/z/rdMj17czW)

Comment: Fascinating. Thank you so much. As you see from my above, I was just unable to figure it out. Thank you!

Comment: ouh, and being able to instantiage the table within makeScheme() is even more convenient because one can use brace-enclosed lists!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to refine joergbrech's solution to one that circumvents the principle of surprise:

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include<functional>

class Table;
class Factory;
class Scheme;

class Table{
    friend class Factory;
    double A=0;
    Table(){}
public:
   ~Table(){std::cout<<"~Table\n";}
};

class Scheme{
    friend class Factory;
    Scheme()=delete;
    void operator=(Scheme const&)=delete;
    //
    Table t;
public:
    Scheme( std::function<Table(void)> f ):t(f()) {}
};

struct Factory{
    Factory()=delete;
    //
    static std::function<Table(void)> makeScheme(){ return Factory::createScheme; }
    //
    static Table createScheme(){ Table t; t.A=2; return t; }
};

struct App{
    Scheme x = Factory::makeScheme();
};

int main(){
    App a;
}
```

To further improve, one would wrap `std::function<Table(void)>` into a class that can only be constructed from factory, and make Scheme`s sole constructor demand an instance of said class. This would assert that scheme cannot be constructed any other way.

Comment: Note that `std::function` uses type erasure involving virtual method calls and heap memory. Since you don't need the type erasure at all, try to avoid it. You can return a function pointer or functor.

Comment: I wasn't even aware of this. Thank you.